# How to model these events?

Tags: probability

I have a List l of events e where each l is independent. For each l this is the order of events that have occurred :

l1 : {e1 , e2 , e3}
l2 : {e1 , e3 , e4 , e5e2}
l3 : {e1 , e2 , e3 , e6}
The event space is is 2^3 : {e1e1e1 , e2e1e2 , e3e1e3 , e4e2e1 , e5e2e2 , e6e2e3 , e3e3, e2e1 , e3e2} I'm assuming each event e is independent.

Out of entire list of events e1...e6 the P(e1 , e2) = P(e1) + P(e2) = 1/3

But how to find P(e1,e2,e3) including information in Given that I have the ordering of events for l1,l2,l3 ? Is can this be used to more accurately predict P(e1,e2,e3) = 2/3 as this event (e1,e2,e3) has occurred occured in l1, l3 but not l2 ?

How to model P(e1,e2,e3)& l3 ?

Update :

I have a List l of events e where each l is independent. For each l this is the order of events that have occurred :

```
l1 : {e1 , e2}
l2 : {e1 , e3 , e2}
l3 : {e1 , e2 , e3}
```

The event space is 2^3 : `{e1e1 , e1e2 , e1e3 , e2e1 , e2e2 , e2e3 , e3e3, e2e1 , e3e2}`
I'm assuming each event e is independent.

Out of entire list of events e1...e6 the P(e1 , e2) = P(e1) + P(e2) = 1/3

Given that I have the ordering of events for l1,l2,l3 can this be used to more accurately predict P(e1,e2) as this event has occured in l1 ?& l3 ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: @Shailesh does this make more sense ?